# Bitmap.SetResolution creates unprecise values when saved

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, resolution

I'm working on a program to check all PNG images in a directory for correct resolutions and reset the incorrect ones. For every incorrect file I use the code below to reset its resolution.

```
float ppi = 96.0F;
string absolutePath = "...";
[...]
FileStream fs = new FileStream(absolutePath, FileMode.Open);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();
if (image != null)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
    bitmap.SetResolution(ppi, ppi);
    bitmap.Save(absolutePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

When I read the resolution infos from the bitmap variable (bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution) after saving they are printed out correct (96).

But when I restart the program the same files are displayed as wrong. Now all resolutions are set to 95,9866. Before there were many different values.

I already tried to cast the ppi for SetResolution as integer, without success.

Did I make any mistakes or is this a problem with the file format? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is a normal mishap, PNG specifies the resolution in metric units in the pHYs chunk.  96 dots per inch, after conversion to meters, does not produce a nice round number that can be stored in an integer.  96 x 1000 / 25.4 = 3779.52.., truncated to 3779.  Reading it back produces 3779 / 1000 * 25.4 = 95.9866.  Inevitably.  Keep moving, nothing to see here.

Comment: The problem is that the images shall be used in WPF, which has a default of 96 DPI and starts scaling different resolutions. This used to create some really ugly graphics in another software. Is there a way to remove the DPI info from the file so that WPF will not scale them at all?

Comment: Hmm, that is an imaginary problem.  It is only off by 0.014%, not a heckofalot of scaling going on.  You'd need a monitor with 7000 pixels of resolution before you could possibly notice.  Other than nobody having one, or having eyes good enough, nobody would ever run such a monitor at 96 dpi.  Keep moving, nothing tested here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out the resolution can not be set exactly due to the conversion between imperial and metrical units in the file format. So I found a way to remove it entirely:

Ken Silverman's tool [PNGOUT.exe](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm) is used to optimize PNG images and thereby removes all explicit DPI information. Once removed, WPF assumes the image's resolution as it's default 96 DPI resolution. If the image is used with it's original measures no scaling is needed - which might also improve the performance of the UI. But the performance impact is still to be tested.

Comment: This is very unwise.  If you ever do meet that user with the 7000 pixel monitor, and those days are getting closer with 4k monitors common today, then that image is nothing but a postage stamp.  The *requirement* for rescaling is an inconvenient truth.